# How to insert tuplets in module tracker software

Tags: composition, software, tuplet

I've used [music trackers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_tracker) in the past, specially ModPlug Tracker (now called [OpenMPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMPT)), and I never knew how to insert tuplets.

[image: Capture of OpenMPT]

In the image above ([from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:OpenMPT-1.18.01.00.png)), you can see the characteristic vertical patterns of tracking editors. It's all very intuitive until you want to put a triplet here or there.

How do I add, in my case, triplets to a mod track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this in the FamiTracker Wiki (FamiTracker is a NES/Famicom-based tracker for Windows), under [Editing](http://famitracker.com/wiki/index.php?title=Frequently_Asked_Questions#Editing):

> **Q:** *How do I write triplets?*
>  
>   **A:** There are several valid ways to insert triplets in your module, but one of the most common ones is to use the
>   [**Gxx**](http://famitracker.com/wiki/index.php?title=Gxx) command. If
>   your module's tempo and speed are set to 150 and 6, respectively, then
>   you can use **G02** and **G04** on your triplet's second and third
>   notes, and you will get perfect triplets. Bear in mind that if you are
>   using a different tempo, different values will be required, so mess
>   around with that until you get the sound you like.

This **Gxx** command is the note delay effect in FamiTracker.

According to the [OpenMPT Wiki](https://wiki.openmpt.org/Manual:_Effect_Reference), the command for the note delay effect in OpenMPT is **SDx** (x being the number of ticks to be delayed).

I have not tried this delay note effect, as I don't have OpenMPT in current computer, but there's another option to insert/play tuplets that should work on every tracker software:

Set the pattern row count to the lowest common denominator of your time signature and tuplet number. For example, for triplets in a 4/4 time, the pattern row should be set to twelve. Then, quarter note triplets should go on each fourth line, and standard quarter notes in each third line.

This method seems kind of obvious now but it never occured to me. I found it in the last message of [this thread](https://forum.openmpt.org/index.php?topic=4406.0), in the OpenMPT forums.